Unable to Run Android Automtive app on Tomtom emulator says "Please contact car services"
Unable to run Android Automotive app on the tomtom emulator shows "Please contact car services ".
The logcat error shows
No handlers found for intent: 
Intent { act=android.car.template.host.RendererService id=0/160887687 (has extras) }

Want to run android automtoive app on tomtom emulator

Since the TomTom Digital Cockpit emulator is not publicly available, you may be better served contacting TomTom for assistance.

so I have had the same issue but I was unsure how to fix this but I have some recommendations on how to fix it If your Android Auto keeps disconnecting or isn’t working in the car, there are a number of possible explanations, including:
You may be using a car or smartphone that’s not Android Auto compatible.
You may have software issues, including an outdated Android operating system or Android Auto app.
You may have a bad wired or wireless connection.
You may be using a faulty app.
You may be trying to connect Android Auto to the wrong vehicle.
You may have changed some settings that affect your Android Auto connection.
And definitely Make sure your phone, car, and apps are compatible

Then I'm also not 100% sure that's right

Uninstall and reinstall the Android Auto app
At this point, if you open Android Auto and it’s still not working or you’re stuck wondering, “why won’t my phone connect to my car?” try uninstalling and reinstalling the app. Doing so can sometimes resolve any remaining glitches.
After you uninstall the app, make sure you restart your device before you redownload Android Auto from the Google Play Store again.

This question is about Android Automotive, which is separate and distinct from Android Auto.
